# When I try to get data from flutter firebase realtime database I got NULL

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

When I try to get the name of the current user from the database I got NULL in the userName variable.

```
Future<String?> getName(String email) async {
final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('users');
final query = ref.orderByChild('Email').equalTo(email);

final snap = await query.once();
final snapshot = snap.snapshot;

if (snapshot.value != null) {
  final data = snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;

  data.forEach((key, value) {
    final name = value['userType'];
    if (name is String) {
      userName = name;
    }
  });
}
}
```

I want the name to be saved in a global variable called userName but it's always shoing null When I try to use it on the screen in a Text() widget.

Comment: Are you sure you use right key inside forEach? `final name = value['userType'];`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show an asynchronously loaded value in the UI, you can do so with a `FutureBuilder`.

First, change your `getName` function so that it actually returns a value:

```
Future<String?> getName(String email) async {
  final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('users');
  final query = ref.orderByChild('Email').equalTo(email);
  
  final snap = await query.once();
  final snapshot = snap.snapshot;
  
  if (snapshot.value != null) {
    final data = snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
  
    data.forEach((key, value) {
      final name = value['userType'];
      if (name is String) {
        userName = name;
      }
    });
  }
  return userName; // 
}
```

Now to display this value in the UI, wire up a `FutureBuilder` like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: getName,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) return Text("ERROR: ${snapshot.error}");
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();

      var data = snapshot.data!
      return Text("$data");
    }
  )
  ...
```

Also see the [documentation for `FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and the codelab on [async programming](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await).